# Flutter : firebase MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having this problem about flutter and firebase(realtime-database).

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Query#observe on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database)

Here is the error in terminal
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPbkp.png)

```
// error message
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Query#observe on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
#2      Query._observe.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase_database/src/query.dart:50:38)
#3      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:820:24)
#4      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:215:7)
#5      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:833:19)
#6      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:475:9)
#7      Stream.first (dart:async/stream.dart:1254:25)
#8      Query.once (package:firebase_database/src/query.dart:84:55)
#9      _IoTState.initState (package:flutter_try_iot/main.dart:36:13)
#10     StatefulElement._f<…>
```

I'm trying to get data from firebase to display in flutter app.

- Here is my code main.dart

```dart
class _IoTState extends State<IoT> {
  final getIot = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  final getData = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('xxx-xxx');
  String temperatue = "0";
  String illuminance = "0";
  List<String> temp = [];
  List<String> light = [];

  @override
  void initState(){
    getData.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
      if (snapshot.value == null) {
        print("Item doesn't exist in the db");
      } else {

        print("Item exists in the db");
      }
      });
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7ACADA),
        title: Text(
          "IoT ZigBee Simulation",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFF1A1244)
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

- pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.5
firebase_database: ^3.1.6
flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
fl_chart: ^0.10.1
```

- I follow instructions to add ios to firebase .[ios add firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i49F4.png)
- no issues found by flutter doctor
- I follow other peoples suggestion to do flutter clean & flutter packages get, but still not able to fix this problem
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13971
  [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZNqN.png)
- Also pop up a window telling me The file “Runner.xcworkspace” has been modified by another application" everytime I execute flutter clean/ flutter packages get
- I successfully connect to firebase yesterday, but after I close my simulator I start to receive error message
  [success picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwX8E.jpg)
- Please give me some solution or advice to fix this problem, thanks.
- Please tell me if I need to provide additional information

Comment: Please do not use screen shots to communicate error messages - your post is much more likely to get help if you include the actual error as text.

Comment: Are you using cloud firestore? if yes, then add `cloud_firestore:` plugin in your pubspec.yaml.

Comment: @HardikKumar I'm using realtime-database

Comment: Try `flutter upgrade` then `flutter run -v`. It may work.